# Delete Line in Csv file from selected line in Listbox

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, listbox

I have this little interface that has a listbox that contains lines of text from a bmi.csv file i know how to remove the line from the listbox but not how to remove the line from the csv file?

[Pic of the interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P50dh.png)

I import the csv data with this code here

```
with open('Bmi.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        listbox.insert(END, row)
    fr.close()
```

this is my button to call the remove item function

```
mbutton = Button(text="Remove Item", command=removeitem).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=N)
```

and this is my remove item function

```
def removeitem():
    fr = open('Bmi.csv', 'r')
    value=str((listbox.get(ACTIVE)))
    lines = fr.readlines()
    fr.close()
    fr = open("Bmi.csv","w")
    for line in lines:
        if line!=value:
            f.write(line)
    listbox.delete(ANCHOR)
    fr.close()
```

I was attempting to get the string of the selected line in the linebox then search the csv file for that string then remove it but i heard i will need to recreate the csv when doing so how can i do this?

Comment: I think you just need to stay consistant with how you open the file, for intance the first time you specify `newline=""` but in `removeitem` you do not so lines will not represent the same data.  other then that I think the code you have will work fine.

Comment: if it still doesn't work you can try implementing reader and writer objects: `lines = list(csv.reader(fr))` and `write = csv.writer(fr) ; for line in lines: if line!=value: write.writerow(line)`

Comment: I just tried this it is good it is removing the line but leaving "[]" in its place before and after the line so when i removed 2 items it has [] on each line for 3 lines on where it used to be

Comment: oh dear, I just realized you are overriding the original file, is it possible you messed up the original data when testing?  (I hope you have a backup)

Comment: i dont mind about any of the orignal data because when it is done im going to submit it to my lecturer blank so any data he adds in the will be the only data showen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your file is in csv format it still uses basic text format, since you are only displaying text in the `Listbox` there is no need to include csv operations at all:

```
with open('Bmi.csv', newline='') as f:
    #are you sure the newline ^ should be ''?
    for row in f:
        listbox.insert(END, row)
    #fr.close() #the with statement closes f, not sure what fr is...
```

This way by writing the lines into the listbox and back into the file in the same way it will not change the data like adding `[]` where it should not be.

Although this might break other functionality of your program that assume the data was loaded as csv, the only issue is that `csv.reader` assumes by default that the data is seperated by commas but looking at the screenshot you provided your data looks more like it is tab `\t` seperated, so you should specify that when reading from the file.

```
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
```

Then it will correctly recognize your data and there won't be any odd `[]` added on. (;

However what would be even easier if each line of the csv directly corresponds to each line of the Listbox just use `.curselection` to get the selected lines and use `enumerate` to keep a line count:

```
def removeitem():
    fr = open('Bmi.csv', 'r')
    removed_lines = listbox.curselection()
    #  ^ just get line numbers with ^ this
    lines = fr.readlines()
    fr.close()
    fr = open("Bmi.csv","w")
   # ^ you use the variable fr here but f below...
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if i not in removed_lines:
             # ^ use in operator since removed_lines is a tuple
             # it is worth noting that this has the advantage of working if multiple lines are selected
            f.write(line)
          # ^ this is f but the file is fr
          #I'm pretty sure this one is a typo
    listbox.delete(ANCHOR)
    # ^ this may not work if multiple lines are selected
    fr.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much i must have went through my code over and over and didnt even notice the "f" instead of fr thanks so much Tadhg!